Stream video using HTTP Range requests with FastAPI and Pyrogram
The current code uses FastAPI and Pyrogram to create a video streaming server. The server should support HTTP Range requests to allow streaming of video segments but the video client is not able to skip forward or backward during streaming as expected.
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from pyrogram import Client
from starlette.responses import StreamingResponse

app = FastAPI()
client = Client("my_account", api_id=......, api_hash="....")

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    await client.start()

@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown_event():
    await client.stop()

@app.get('/stream/{file_id}')
async def stream(file_id: str, request: Request):
    range_header = request.headers.get('Range', None)
    start, end = 0, None
    if range_header:
        byte1, byte2 = range_header.replace('bytes=', '').split('-')
        start = int(byte1)
        if byte2:
            end = int(byte2)

    async def generate():
        offset = start // (1024 * 1024)  # Convert start to chunks
        limit = (1 << 31) - 1  # Default limit
        if end is not None:
            limit = (end - start) // (1024 * 1024) + 1  # Convert end to chunks
        async for chunk in client.stream_media(file_id, offset=offset, limit=limit):
            yield chunk

    response = StreamingResponse(generate(), media_type='video/mp4')
    response.headers['Accept-Ranges'] = 'bytes'
    if range_header:
        response.status_code = 206
        response.headers['Content-Range'] = f'bytes {start}-{end if end else ""}/*'
    return response

An example of log
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\mix\nginx_stream\teldrive\playstream> uvicorn editor:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 11840
INFO:     Started server process [10540]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:11840 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:56602 - "GET /stream/BAACAgQAAx0Eb1YTJQABBYGv............ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:56601 - "GET /stream/BAACAgQAAx0Eb1YTJQABBYGv............ HTTP/1.1" 206 Partial Content

Example of URL streaming is http://127.0.0.1:11840/stream/BAACAgQAAx0Eb1.... 
BAACAgQAAx0Eb1.... is file_id from telegram

what video client do you means? Maybe you should use print() to see what you get from video client and what you have in variables when you generate code.
